# How to send a mail/write to other user through a shell script? How to send EOF?

Tags: command-line, scripts

```
if [ who | grep $user | grep pts ]
then
              write $user
                   message here
                   EOF
fi
```

Here if I execute it, it is blocking at write and I have to enter a message manually and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>.

Is there a way to send message and EOF through program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are probably looking for is the following style of writing it (equivalent to other methods)

```
write $user <<EOF
    message here
    as opposed to the
       echo "asd" | write $user
    method, using here-doc redirection transparently allows multiple lines
    and reads everything until seeing the delimiter
    so the sent message end here:
EOF
```

Note: you are not directly "sending an EOF" here, the shell just understands the word "EOF" as your chosen mark of ending the input and will end the input there - and write doesnt ask you to press ctrl+d in this case, because it is reading from the stuff the shell is piping to it.

Note 2: You may find useful knowing that pretty much *every* comand-line tool in the unix world allows for this kind of default shell tricks, as they are only relying on the incredibly universal concept of stdin - write, as many other tools, will read from what is piped to it - and only ask the user interactively for input if none such is present and a user input method would make sense.

For more info, there is a question asking for exactly this over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500436/how-does-cat-eof-work-in-bash

Answer (score 4):

You can [pipeline your input from one program to another](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html) like this:

```
echo "message here"|write $user
```

or like this:

```
cat /tmp/message|write $user
```

Comment: Or even `write $user < /tmp/message`.